# What is the proper way to import PHP project into PhpStorm, which is on different host through SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, phpstorm

I have a development server which has a checked out Git repository
What would be the best way to use PhpStorm for the files on the remote server?

The obvious thing is to choose PhpStorm's option of

- Create project from existing files, then
- Web server is on remote host, files are accessible through SFTP

However when going this route, the Git repo is not synchronized. As such, PhpStorm is unaware of Git.

An alternative is to choose

- Check out from version control

However now I have two checkouts, one locally, and one on the server. Now if I for example make a commit, this is not reflected on the remote server.

Is there a way to cater to my situation in which PhpStorm knows about the files *and* I only have to deal with one Git state?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out from version control on your local machine. Git is a **distributed** version control system, so the whole point is to be able to use it without needing a live connection to a server.

Since you have SSH access, just clone the repo from the server:

```
git clone ssh://user@server.com/path/to/git/repo
```

If you already have a copy of the repo locally, then add the server's Git repo as a remote:

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@server.com/path/to/git/repo
```

Then after you have committed locally, you can do `git push` to update the server. If you want to avoid the extra step, then just combine commit and push into one step with an alias:

```
git config alias.comush '!git commit && git push'
```

Then you can do `git comush` to commit *and* push.

However, by default Git doesn't allow you to push to the current branch on a non-bare repo. To change this, set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `ignore` on the server:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

Then add a `post-receive` hook to the server repo that does e.g.:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
GIT_WORK_TREE=.. git checkout -f master
```

(Save that at `/path/to/git/repo/.git/hooks/post-receive`.)

This will overwrite the working directory on the server with the latest changes from `master` every time you push. If you use things like the `.gitignore` file properly, then this shouldn't cause any issues, but you can add more error checking to that script if needed.